# How to compare contents of 2 dlls with powershell

Tags: powershell, dll, compare

I would like to compare two dlls contents with each other. I need to ensure that they both have the exact same code,methods,properties,version,etc.

It has to be done in Powershell. I tried the following script on two dlls with the same content but build on a different time. It outputs "files are different". I think it might be build metadata or something that is making the two dlls different?

```
$fileA = "<PathToFile>.dll"

$fileB = "<PathToFile>.dll"


if((Get-FileHash $fileA).hash  -ne (Get-FileHash $fileB).hash)
{
"files are different"
}

else 
{
"Files are the same"
}
```

Comment: "Exact same code" is going to be a bit of a stretch - two versions of the same compiler might output different IL for the same source code

Answer (score -1):

hash only check if 2 files are the same. if there is one bit that is different the hash will be different.

to find the diffrences use this func:

```
   function dll_compare(){
   param($path1,$path2) 
   $first = Get-ChildItem -Path $path1 -Filter *.dll
   $second =  Get-ChildItem -Path $path2 -Filter *.dll
   $diff = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $first -DifferenceObject $second -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTime, VersionInfo -PassThru |
Select Name, Length, LastWriteTime, sideindicator,@{n = "path"; e ={ $_.fullname }}, @{n = "VersionInfo"; e = { $_.VersionInfo.Productversion }Productversion}}
   $diff}
```